# Printing multiple Markers on Android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

So I got this code trying to add markers saved in a DataBase:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    control.conectar();
    ArrayList<Sucursal> sucursales = control.getSucursales();
    control.cerrar();
    LatLng loc;
    for(int x=0;x<sucursales.size();x++){
        loc = new LatLng(sucursales.get(x).getX(), sucursales.get(x).getY());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title(sucursales.get(x).getNombre()));
    }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(20.67711737527203, -103.36349487304688)));
}
```

All the DB rows are getting obtained correctly and the cicle is working, however only the first row seems to be "working" because its not putting it on the right location either.

Ive tried this exact code another time, but I think im missing something now.

Comment: you are adding multiple markers and then moving camera to different location. If you are getting error then post your logcat here

Comment: @AnujSharma I get no errors, and I'm just moving the camera to an "avarage" location so i can see every other one.

Comment: what is your requirement and what are you getting in your results ?

Comment: @SagarNayak I want 13 marks on the map, I only get 1

Comment: you have two case . 1. you can only see 1 marker but there are 13 . 2. you are actually looking at 1 marker and there is actually 1 marker placed. which one is your case . i assume the case 1 .

Comment: I'm going to make a guess. Based on your code I would tell that you are 
exchanging latitude and longitude. Try doing `loc = new LatLng(sucursales.get(x).getY(), sucursales.get(x).getX());`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should take care of is that you have all the data needed in your `sucursales` variable. By doing this you can be sure of you are placing all the markers on the map.

Here you are assuming that all the markers are in the viewport which might not be true in all case so you should latlng bounds here.

Through this you will be sure of you are keeping all markers in the viewport.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder().include(source).include(destination).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
```

In your case , define this before for loop and update in each of the iteration.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
control.conectar();
ArrayList<Sucursal> sucursales = control.getSucursales();
control.cerrar();
LatLng loc;
LatLngBounds bounds=new LatLngBounds.Builder().build();
for(int x=0;x<sucursales.size();x++){
    bounds.including(new LatLng(sucursales.get(x).getX(), sucursales.get(x).getY()));
}
for(int x=0;x<sucursales.size();x++){
    loc = new LatLng(sucursales.get(x).getX(), sucursales.get(x).getY());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title(sucursales.get(x).getNombre()));
}
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
}
```

This will bring all your markers into the viewport.

Do tell if it worked for you and accept this if this is what you have wanted.